# How do I set up HTTP headers in responses generated by Go server running AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm trying to set headers using golang and google app engine . Here's how the trivial code looks like:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/xml")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("header-name", "value")
```

It seems that it's not working on my dev server. I always get the usual headers and

```
content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

When I deploy I get

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Am I doing it wrong or this is a bug (another one)?

Answer (score 5):

It seems the issue was that I set the http code before the custom headers. Be aware that if you have `w.WriteHeader(200)` before `w.Header` the headers will not be set.

Comment: Why did it work properly on your Dev machine? This was my first intuition but the fact that it worked on your machine made me doubt that.

Comment: `// Write writes the data to the connection as part of an HTTP reply. If WriteHeader has not yet been called, Write calls WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) before writing the data.  If the Header does not contain a Content-Type line, Write adds a Content-Type set to the result of passing the initial 512 bytes of written data to DetectContentType.`

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer it didn't work on my dev machine either. However the content-type on the dev machine is different than on the GAE app ( ``text/plain`` vs ``text/html`` ) when no header is set (  ``w.WriteHeader(200)`` is set before ``w.Header``)

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely a bug with the GAE SDK. Unjustified different behaviour is observed between dev and prod environments. I am experiencing the same issue, where I set the headers at a specific order - works on dev but in prod headers are not set.

In dev env, this makes the headers you set return properly:

```
func SignalingHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    data := "test"

    w.Write([]byte(data))

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

}
```

However in prod environment, I have to reverse the order - and use the "write" method only AFTER setting the headers (otherwise it won't work):

```
 func SignalingHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    data := "test"


    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    w.Write([]byte(data))
}
```

To make things work in prod, make sure you do not use the write method after setting any headers.

Comment: According to the documentation you must *always* make all header adjustments *before* any calls to `Write`. If in some environments there is an optimization or other slight difference where under certain circumstances it *happens* to sometime appear to "work", doesn't change that it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Without the rest of the code is hard to predict. However, the underlying reason is likely to be that you already wrote a response before setting the headers.

Either something like this:

```
w.Write([]byte(data))
```

Or something like this:

```
fmt.Printf(w, "A test response")
```